# Python tkinter canvas events not triggering on scrolled region

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a python progrem using Tkint GUI and the canvas element. I attached a scrollbar to the canvas element so that the user can scroll to unseen regions of the canvas. I created a dotted grid that would allow the user to hover over the dots and if clicked the program draws a circle over the dot. Also as the mouse enters and leave each dot, and dashed circle is drawn and erased.

[image]

I also have a print procedures that shows debugging information of the actions performed:

[image]

Everything works on the initially visible portion of the canvas. However, when I scroll down, I noticed that the bounded events of click on hover do work, but the canvas graphics are not being triggered/drawn and nothing appears.

[image]

I can't understand why initially the graphics were successfully drawn, the event bounded and also working, but the canvas graphics just won't work. Is there some issue between the scroll bar and canvas? Here is the code for the initialization of the canvas and scroll bars:

```
    def __init__(self, parent, model, settings, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)       
    self.width = 625
    self.height = 500
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.width, height=self.height, background='white', cursor='arrow')
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.focusDotImage = -1
    print("self.focusDotImage: ", self.focusDotImage)

    # configure the scroll region
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, self.width * 2, self.height * 2))

    # create scrollbars and connect to canvas
    xScroll = tk.Scrollbar(
        self,
        command=self.canvas.xview,
        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL
    )
    xScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='new')

    yScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.canvas.yview)
    yScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')

    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yScroll.set)
    self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xScroll.set)

    # Draw Dotted Grid width
    self.space = 25
    self.dotRadius= 1
    self.nodeRadius = 5
    for i in range(0, self.width):
        for j in range(0, self.height):
            dotItem = self.canvas.create_rectangle(i * self.space-self.dotRadius, j * self.space-self.dotRadius, i * self.space + self.dotRadius,
                                                   j * self.space + self.dotRadius, fill='lightgrey')
            self.canvas.tag_bind(dotItem, '<Enter>', self._on_dot_enter)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(dotItem, '<Leave>', self._on_dot_leave)

    self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)
```

Per comment request, I built a small runnable demo to showcase the weird effects of the canavas/scrolling issue:

```
import tkinter as tk



def _on_click(event):
    print("On click imagine item...", )
    global image_item3
    canvas.delete(image_item3)

def _on_click_canvas(e):
    print("coord {}, {}".format(e.x, e.y))
    canvas.create_oval(e.x, e.y, (e.x+10), (e.y+10), fill='white')


# Create root and canvas
root = tk.Tk()

width = 1024
height = 768

canvas = tk.Canvas(
    root, background='black',
    width=width, height=height,
)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)


image_item = canvas.create_oval((200, 200), (300, 300), fill='white')
image_item2 = canvas.create_oval((300, 300), (400, 400), fill='white')
global image_item3
image_item3 = canvas.create_oval((200, 900), (300, 1000), fill='white')
canvas.tag_bind(image_item3, '<Button-1>', _on_click)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', _on_click_canvas)

# configure the scroll region
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, width * 2, height * 2))

# create scrollbars and connect to canvas
xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(
    root,
    command=canvas.xview,
    orient=tk.HORIZONTAL
)
xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='new')

yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=xscroll.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't run the code you posted. The indentation is broken and it's missing several methods. Please provide a complete but minimal [mcve].

Comment: After the canvas is scrolled, the coordinates of the top-left corner is not `(0, 0)` anymore, but `(event.x, event.y)` is relative to the top-left corner of the canvas.  So `(event.x, event.y)` is not the actual coordinates in the canvas.  You need to use `self.canvas.canvasx()` and `self.canvas.canvasy()` to convert the event coordinates to actual canvas coordinates. Note that in order to identify the issue precisely, it is better to post the missing functions: `self._on_click()`, `self._ondot_enter()` and `self._on_dot_leave()`.

Comment: Sorry about not posting all the code, but unfortunately I was not allowed. I did just post a minimal reproducible example according to the indication of the first comment by Bryan. Sorry it took me a while and I really appreciate your assistance. Let me check to see if that is indeed the case, but I think you are right.

Comment: acw1668: your answer worked! Thank you very much. I tried it in my minimal example:
canvas.create_oval(canvas.canvasx(e.x), canvas.canvasy(e.y), (canvas.canvasx(e.x)+10), (canvas.canvasy(e.y)+10), fill='white') 
And it worked correctly this time. If you write in the answer I will vote it and select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the canvas is scrolled to other region, the coordinates of the top-left corner of the canvas is not `(0, 0)` anymore. However `(event.x, event.y)` is still relative to the top-left corner of the canvas, so `(event.x, event.y)` will not be the actual coordinates in the canvas.

To get the correct coordinates, you can use `self.canvas.canvasx()` and `self.canvas.canvasy()` to convert the event coordinates to actual canvas coordinates.